# Mathematica: flatten a nested list with repetitions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a following list:

```
lis={{1, {2}}, {3, {4, 5, 6}}, {7, {8, 9}}, {10, {11}}};
```

I'd like to obtain this:

```
lis2={{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {10, 11}};
```

I can achieve that using nested tables and calculating the length of the second nested list:

```
Flatten[Table[Table[{lis[[kk, 1]], lis[[kk, 2, ii]]}, {ii, 1, Length[lis[[kk, 2]]]}], {kk, 1, Length[lis]}], 1]
```

It works, but is there a more straightforward way? Perhaps a combination of Map/Thread/Apply?

Comment: Are you aware of the StackExchange site dedicated to Mathematica (mathematica.stackexchange.com)? That might be a better place to ask this question. Most Mathematica experts have moved over there and rarely visit this place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
ArrayFlatten[Distribute[#, List] & /@ lis, 1]
```

=> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {10, 11}}

**Edit**

Or

```
ArrayFlatten[Thread /@ lis, 1]
```

**Edit 2**

Or, slightly simpler, as [Mr Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618728/mr-wizard) points out in a comment:

```
Flatten[Thread /@ lis, 1]
```

Comment: I'd go for plain old `Flatten` myself, but +1 -- that's the way to do it.